# What's the difference between "A = Obj()" and "A = new Obj()"

Tags: c++, object, new-operator

I'm confused by the two different ways and I find both of them are Okay in VS.Can u let me know the nature of the difference?

Comment: What is the type of `A` ?

Comment: first is a function, second is a class constructor

Comment: @mangusta The first one is definitely not a function.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, if `Obj` is a class name. he did not specify that

Comment: @mangusta Seriously, no. Function declarations do not have `=` in the middile.

Comment: @juanchopanza nobody talks about function declaration here. i meant function invokation, not declaration

Comment: @mangusta In that case, both are "functions", by your strange definition of "being a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one creates a default-constructed temporary object, and uses the the copy-constructor (if the assignment is in the declaration of `A`) or the copy-assignment operator to copy from the temporary object to `A`. Then the temporary object is destroyed.

The second creates a default-constructed object on the heap, and returns a pointer to this new object. You must later `delete` this object or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

At this level of understanding, the best advice I can give you is to stay away from `new`. You *will* need it later, for more complex tasks, but don't let the fact that, for instance, Java has a `new` as well fool you. In C++, `new` opens a whole world of issues which don't exist in other languages. One could argue that it's unfortunate that the keyword is identical in different languages... :)

To be more precise, `new` in C++ means, among other things, that you create an object which will **not be automatically removed** from memory when you don't need it anymore. You must remember its location in memory via a **pointer**, and a pointer is a dangerous tool easy to abuse especially for unexperienced programmers.

```
void f()
{
    Obj *a = new Obj();
    // no automatic destruction, the object remains in memory!
}
```